object pronoun + gerund

"Sometimes, I like a few things about being a social media influencer. /
me being a social media influencer.

I have seen people use the first structure, but also the second structure with different nouns or pronouns before gerunds.
If I do not use a noun or pronoun before a gerund, does it mean we are just talking about a general thing?
for example:

Learning a new language can be challenging, but it's rewarding too. 
(here, learning is an object in general and acts as the subject)

unlike,

The dog's constant barking drove the neighbors crazy.

My question is that sometimes, we use just gerund but we talk about a specific person, not in general - "I remember being taken to the zoo every Sunday". (I was taken to the zoo).
But, in the first sentence,
"Sometimes, I like a few things about being a social media influencer. /
me being a social media influencer.
How can I manage the usage of a noun/pronoun before a gerund? Or when to use which one?

I would say that it's obvious that the speaker is referring to their own experience, so the 'me' isn't really necessary.

@KateBunting do you know any reference?

In the examples, learning is a noun form, and so is barking. "Me being" is slangy, but it's a verb.

The subject of a gerund takes the possessive case:

I like a few things about my being a social influencer.

That said, there aren't a lot of people who know that rule or use it in practice, so it wouldn't be unusual in informal English to hear:

I like a few things about me being a social influencer.

Or, even better:

I like a few things about being a social influencer.


I like a few things about me being a social influencer. maybe using 'me' emphasizes the state of mine. and without 'the subject' we are talking about 'the state of being a social influencer' in general.

This Ngram finds instances of like about being but none of like about me being.
Some of the instances are from sentences like "You can say what you like about being xxx" which refer to the experience in general. But questions such as "What do you like about being a girl/a Christian/an actor?" (the first three examples) obviously refer to the person's own experience of being those things. Your example "I remember being taken to the zoo" means that the memory is of you being taken, unless you include someone else's name.
The example you claim to have seen - "I like a few things about me being a social influencer" doesn't seem like standard English to me, though it may be one of those nonstandard expressions that are creeping into use.
